# Error to set visibility while mainactivity launch

Tags: android

I am just tried to make an app to check my internet connection is on or not. If internet connection is not available then it will show a separate `LinearLayout` with full `match_parent` but it will not work with visibility. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:background="#c6c6c9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/error"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="connect to Internet"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

 public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Take a Hotspot Dude...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        r1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where are `r1`'s instantiation?

Comment: write full code of mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between layouts after determining connectivity status, consider having two different layouts entirely, and setting the ContentView to the layout that fits the current conditions.

```
public boolean isOnline() {

ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Take a Hotspot Dude...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    r1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.network_doesnt_exist);

    return false;
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.network_exists)
}
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to switch between items within your layout itself, which may get a little messy, set the visibility status to 'GONE'

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Use this for whichever items you'd like to make disappear entirely from the layout, meaning they're not just hidden but also not included in any layout_weight or such distributions.

I hope this helps answer your question!